# JavaScript Encapsulation / JQuery

Tags: javascript, oop, namespaces, encapsulation

I am trying to figure out how to keep my page variables in my application from being defined globally. I've come up with a few methods but am wondering if there is a general standard approach people use.

I've got my plugin design pattern down using this approach: http://www.virgentech.com/blog/2009/10/building-object-oriented-jquery-plugin.html. But I'm just not sure how to handle my page level encapsulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, it is achieved like this:

```
(function(){

    var myLocal = "I'm local!";

    window.myGlobal = "I'm global!";

})();
```

Comment: When I know that jQuery is around, I usually pollute the `$` namespace instead of `window`.  `$.myCompany` becomes the hook point, everything else gets wrapped in a function enclosure.

Comment: +1 This is, in fact, the approach jQuery itself uses for the same purpose.  The entire contents of jquery.js are wrapped like so: `(function(window, undefined) { ... })(window);`  Although I don't really understand the need to pass `window` into the function.  Even if `window` wasn't passed, I thought it would still be available from within the container function.

Answer (score 0):

Vincent's got the most watertight approach (wrap everything in a function).

The other thing people do is to define a global object that more or less works as a namespace for your package.

```
window.ChrisPkg = {
   global1: ['a','b','c'],
   global2: 42
   globalfunc: function () { alert('hello world!'); }
}

ChrisPkg.extraGlobal = 'foo';
```